# Delete all but top record in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to write a script to delete all records except for the top one (if it's just any one that's fine too, there just have to be one record left). Here's the format I have as of now:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1 ))
```

But I realize that LIMIT is not a recognized function in SQL server 2005, so I'm kind of stuck as to what to do. Anyone have any expert knowledge on this topic? And these records are NOT duplicated, I just want to take out all but one record.

UPDATE:

I realized that what I'm trying to accomplish here isn't completely clear. What I need to do is to delete all but the top record in this table given that it has the same value in another column (let's call it 'anotherid').

so its like from this:

```
id        value       anotherid       
1          3           1
2          4           1
3          5           2
4          6           2
5          7           2
```

To this:

```
id        value       anotherid       
1          3           1
3          5           2
```

Comment: Is the ordering coincidental? You chose id 1 because id is lowest for anotherid = 1? Or because value is lowest for anotherid = 1? Or some other reason?

Comment: It's coincidental, anotherid is not unique and I just want it so that here will be only one instance of anotherid record left on the table

Comment: So you don't care which row for anotherid = 1 remains, as long as it's only one?

Comment: yes, because i will be populating it with the correct data with an update query later, it's just that i can't populate both field under same 'anotherid' with the same data because of a UK constraint

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer, it will keep the lowest id for each anotherid value. The table variable is used just to demonstrate it all in one script.

Comment: It work liked a charm! thank you so much for your help!! I was wondering if you don't mind going the extra mile, explain why the ";" were there and what "OVER (PARTITION...)" means? This is completely new to me and I would love to understand the logic behind it :)

Comment: `;` is there because a CTE (the `WITH` part) needs to be preceded by a semi-colon. Without it, users may copy that part of the answer into existing code, the previous statement doesn't have a semi-colon, and they complain that the code I provided didn't work. So adding a leading semi-colon avoids that issue. As for the OVER clause, tough to really give a tutorial on that, perhaps start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: That should be enough for me to learn more about SQL. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the update, as I understand it:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(id INT, value INT, anotherid INT);

INSERT @x SELECT 1, 3, 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 4, 1
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 5, 2
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 6, 2
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 7, 2;

;WITH y AS 
(
  SELECT id, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (PARTITION BY anotherid ORDER BY id) -- or order by value?
   FROM @x -- replace with your dbo.tablename
)
DELETE y WHERE rn > 1;

SELECT id, value, anotherid FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
id  value  anotherid
--- ------ ---------
1   3      1
3   5      2
```

---

**Answer to original question**

A couple of other options:

```
-- use a CTE to identify the highest id,
-- then delete all rows except that one
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT id, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) 
  FROM dbo.table
)
DELETE x WHERE rn > 1;

-- use a subquery to get the max, and delete
-- all id values lower than that result
DELETE dbo.table WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM dbo.table);
```

Note that these will behave differently if `id` is not unique. Let's say the highest `id` is `10`, and there are three rows with `id = 10`. The top answer will leave one row in the table; the bottom answer (and Adrian's answer) will leave three rows. If this is your scenario and your intention is to leave exactly one row in the table even in the event of a tie, you can add additional tie-breaking criteria to the `ORDER BY` in the top query.

Answer (score 9):

```
delete from table where id <> (select top 1 id from table order by id desc)
```

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there's some kind of unique identifier on your table?

for that do something like this

```
delete from [table] 
where [uniqueColumn] <> 'value';
```

If you don't have unique columns on.
manually go into the table,
change a value on the row you want to be something unique like "OMGWTFBBQSauce".
Then do

```
delete from [table] 
where [column] <> 'OMGWTFBBQSauce';
```